# Problems setting up startmail client on ipad

Tags: ipad, mail.app, imap

I've tried twice from scratch to set up an IMAP account for Startmail on my ipad and the steps appear to be simple however when I try to use it I'm told that either my userid or password is incorrect on my imap connection.  I've verifed these and they are correct.  I'm familiar with setting up an IMAP client to Startmail because I've done it on other hardware.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: When entering your account name, are you using the full email address?

Comment: Have you contacted their tech support? If so what did they say, if not that would be the first place to try.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously logged into the Startmail web client on the iPad and iOS stored the password automatically without my being aware of it.  One of the security features of Startmail is that it assigns a new password to any device that accesses it using IMAP.  When I set up the IMAP account on the iPad I entered the new, device specific password but iOS over-rode it with the stored, web-client value.  Since it was typing in a password field I couldn't see it.  When I found the stored password and deleted it I was able to set up the IMAP account following Startmail's instructions.